# In what units is the size distribution for blob types?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-stress-tool

I'm trying to use the [Cassandra stress tool](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress.html) but I don't know the unit for the size distribution for a blob column.

[The blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema) doesn't really help in this regard either.

So the question is when I specify a `columnspec` on a blob column like this:

```
columnspec:
  - name: data
    size: gaussian(10000..250000, 2)
```

What units are the min/max referring to? Is this bits, bytes, MB, GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand [this code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/tools/stress/src/org/apache/cassandra/stress/generate/values/HexBytes.java) correctly (and assuming this is where I should be looking), particularly the constructor:

```java
public HexBytes(String name, GeneratorConfig config)
{
    super(BytesType.instance, config, name, ByteBuffer.class);
    bytes = new byte[(int) sizeDistribution.maxValue()];
}
```

It is initializing a `byte[]` with the distribution's max value.

In that case the size would correspond to bytes.

Comment: Hello @FGreg, we are following same above setting with blob column, but getting `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Batch too large` error. have you any idea? why in the case of us, we are getting this error?